# How to use yield with callback based loops?

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous, yield

Although the primary purpose of the yield keyword is to provide iterators over some data, it is also rather convenient to use it to create asynchronous loops:

```
function* bigLoop() {
    // Some nested loops
    for( ... ) {
        for( ... ) {
            // Yields current progress, eg. when parsing file
            // or processing an image                        
            yield percentCompleted;
        }
    }
}
```

This can then be called asynchronously:

```
function big_loop_async(delay) {
    var iterator = big_loop();
    function doNext() {
        var next = iterator.next();
        var percent_done = next.done?100:next.value;
        console.log(percent_done, " % done.");
        // start next iteration after delay, allowing other events to be processed
        if(!next.done)
            setTimeout(doNext, delay);
    }
    setTimeout(doNext, delay);
}
```

However, in modern javascript, callback based loops have become quite popular. We have `Array.prototype.forEach`, `Array.prototype.find` or `Array.prototype.sort`. All of these are based on a callback passed for each iteration. I even heard it to be recommended that we use these if we can, because they can be optimized better than standard for loops.

I also often use callback based loops to abstract away some complex looping pattern.

And the question here is, is it possible to turn those into `yield` based iterators? As a simple example, consider I wanted you to sort an array asynchronously.

Comment: Would sorting an array asynchronously (with a generator and a single thread of js), have any benefits?

Comment: @DavinTryon It's an *example*, examples are not designed to be practical, but to be easy to understand. Anyway, array long enough might take too long to sort and could, for example, disconnect people from your server or lag user's browser.

Comment: @TomášZato This is a [good article](http://raganwald.com/2016/05/07/javascript-generators-for-people-who-dont-give-a-shit-about-getting-stuff-done.html) that you might find interesting (unfortunate title).  So, short answer to your OP, is yes it can be done.

Comment: @DavinTryon I had read the article you suggested. It's a very good article for generators but I don't think it contains any methods to solve this problem.

Comment: "*I even heard it to be recommended that we use these if we can, because they can be optimized better than standard for loops.*" - that is no longer true

Comment: @Bergi Yes, soon after posting this I actually looked into that and found them to be slower in almost all cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **tl;dr: You can’t do that, but check out this other thing you *can* do with the latest V8 and [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/):**
>
> ```
> async function asyncReduce() {
>     const sum = await Promise.reduce(
>         [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
>         async (m, n) => m + await Promise.delay(200, n),
>         0
>     );
>
>     console.log(sum);
> }
> ```

No, it’s not possible to make `Array.prototype.sort` accept the results of comparisons asynchronously from its comparison function; you would have to reimplement it entirely. For other individual cases, there might be hacks, like a coroutiney `forEach` (which doesn’t even necessarily work as you’d expect, because every generator will run until its first `yield` before one continues from a `yield`):

```
function syncForEach() {
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].forEach(function (x) {
        console.log(x);
    });
}
```

```
function delayed(x) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(x), Math.random() * 1000 | 0);
    });
}

function* chain(iterators) {
    for (const it of iterators) {
        yield* it;
    }
}

function* asyncForEach() {
    yield* chain(
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map(function* (x) {
            console.log(yield delayed(x));
        })
    );
}
```

and `reduce`, which works nicely by nature (until you look at performance):

```
function syncReduce() {
    const sum = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].reduce(function (m, n) {
        return m + n;
    }, 0);

    console.log(sum);
}
```

```
function* asyncReduce() {
    const sum = yield* [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].reduce(function* (m, n) {
        return (yield* m) + (yield delayed(n));
    }, function* () { return 0; }());

    console.log(sum);
}
```

but yeah, no magic wand for all functions.

Ideally, you’d add alternate promise-based implementations for all these functions – popular promise libraries, like bluebird, already do this for `map` and `reduce`, for example – and use `async`/`await` instead of generators (because `async` functions return promises):

```
async function asyncReduce() {
    const sum = await Promise.reduce(
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        async (m, n) => m + await delayed(n),
        0
    );

    console.log(sum);
}
```

You wouldn’t need to wait for `async` support to do this so much if ECMAScript had sane decorators like Python, either:

```
@Promise.coroutine
function* add(m, n) {
    return m + (yield delayed(n));
}

@Promise.coroutine
function* asyncReduce() {
    const sum = yield Promise.reduce([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], add, 0);

    console.log(sum);
}
```

… but it doesn’t and so you do. Or you can live with code like this:

```
const asyncReduce = Promise.coroutine(function* () {
    const sum = yield Promise.reduce([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], Promise.coroutine(function* (m, n) {
        return m + (yield delayed(n));
    }), 0);

    console.log(sum);
});
```